# Displaying of the data in the gridview based on the search criteria using generics concept of .net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i am new to .net..i have to develop an asp.net application.

The UI of the web page will have a Data-bound Grid control on the Home page and there will be a Textbox where users can enter their search criteria.
I know to do this by using ado.net concept...

But i am supposed to do it using generics concept.How can i store the values in the generic list or dictionary of .net and filter the data based on the text entered in the text box.

Please help me out..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I don't understand how the `GridView` is related to the `List<T>` or `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`. If you want to filter the grid you should use the database. So you should use the _search criteria_ as parameter for your select query.

Comment: thanks Tim..Yes you are right.but i am hard coding the data in to list.even i have binded it to grid.But i am not getting how to filter it based on the data entered in the text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed bind a `GridView` to `List<T>`, I do it all the time, like this:

Create a POCO for the data

```
public class SomeData
{
  public string SomeField {get;set;}
  public string SomeOtherField {get;set;}
}
```

Build the list (either manually or as a result a DB query) e.g.

```
var mylist = new List<SomeData>();
var myitem = new SomeData()
{
  SomeField = "Hello",
  SomeOtherField = "World"
};
```

To Filter the data do something like this:

```
myfilter = MyTextBox.Value;
mylist = mylist.Where(somedata => somedata.SomeField.Equals(myfiltervalue)).ToList();
```

Bind it to the GridView

```
mygridview.DataSource = mylist;
mygridview.DataBind();
```

And this is it!!

Comment: Hi Dave i have done this..how can i search the list based on the data entered in the text box and display only those data that matches the search criteria.

Comment: @user2710511 - Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: can u tel me what is somedata means

Comment: I mean if you dont mind can you explain me filter code statements please

Comment: No problem. The .Where() is a Linq Extension method that takes a 'Lamda Expression' as a parameter. The 'somedata' variable could be named anything. In a nutshell, a lamda expression is an anonymous function that can take parameters.

Comment: In my example somedata => somedata.SomeField.Equal(...) means, that each item in the list is projected into an anonymous function (denoted by =>) passing the item as a parameter. The anon function returns true or false (the .Equals(...) bit).

Comment: Some useful links on Lambdas http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33769/Basics-of-LINQ-Lamda-Expressions

Comment: I am getting the following error..Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Comment: I am not able to post it because my reputation in below 10

Comment: In button search click i ve written the following lines             string mySearch = txtSearch.Text;
         listdata = listdata.Where(somedata => somedata.Id.Equals(mySearch)).ToList();
         GridView1.DataSource = listdata;
        GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: okay, I'm Guessing that somedata.Id is null. what data type is it? if it is a string type try this: !string.IsNullOrEmpty(somedata.Id) && somedata.Id.Equals(mySearch).

Comment: Brilliant!! Pleased to help and glad you got it working! Can you mark as answered please.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know ado.net and how to bind gridview.

You just need to iterate through your database resultset and add it to list and bind it.

Following link might help you to begin with:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-bind-GridView-with-Generic-List-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Pass your textbox value to your database query/stored procedure as parameter and return the result based on search value.

**Edit:**

You may want to use FindAll, Find method.

Check below link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa701359(VS.80).aspx

Comment: thanks Nilesh..Actually i am not supposed to use database..can you tell me the way how can i search the generic list.